# Gradle wrapper not found issue when building a flutter apk

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-build, flutter-run

I am getting below error when I am trying to build apk or run it on a simulator.
I tried with vs Code and Android Studio both, but the same error.

But when I am running the app on a browser or as a windows app, it's working perfectly.

Error: -

```
PS D:\Final_Code_GIT\Research & Development\AndroidApp\flutter_application> flutter build apk
Building with sound null safety

'Development\AndroidApp\flutter_application\android\' is not recognized as an internal or external 
command,operable program or batch file.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           363ms

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance, Stay Safe.

Comment: "Research & Development" remove space  and rename this folder to something like "Research&Development" or "ResearchAndDevelopment" and then try building app

Comment: Thank You Sir , Its working now . @Aakashkondhalkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Research & Development" remove space and rename this folder to something like "Research&Development" or "ResearchAndDevelopment" and then try building app
– Aakash kondhalkar